# How to normalise a Union Type (T | Option[T])?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I have the following `case class`:

```
case class Example[T](
    obj: Option[T] | T = None,
)
```

This allows me to construct it like `Example(myObject)` instead of `Example(Some(myObject))`.

To work with obj I need to normalise it to `Option[T]`:

```
  lazy val maybeIn = obj match
    case o: Option[T] => o
    case o: T => Some(o)
```

`the type test for Option[T] cannot be checked at runtime`

I tried with `TypeTest` but I got also warnings - or the solutions I found look really complicated - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69608091/2750966

Is there a better way to achieve this pattern in **Scala 3**?

Comment: The type `Option[T] | T` doesn't make sense. What you want is actually a facility method to create an `Some[T]` from `T` when creating an `Example` rather than doing some unification when using it. See below answer from @ziggystar.

Comment: You cannot match on `Option[T]` because that is not a concrete type. You could try `Option[_]` if that's what you think you want.
The `T` type is abstract, so you cannot match/instanceOf on it either...  You could just do `o =>` .... 
So it's best to reconsider your design choices a bit.

Comment: What happen if `T=Option[A]`? Or even `T = Option[Option[B]]` ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65256690/best-way-to-model-optional-arguments

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, thanks your answer explains it really nicely. 

You mention "Maybe the introduction of union types could open the possibility of a simpler way to encode optional arguments?" 
This question is exactly about this - is there a nice pattern with the union types. So do you have an answer yet?

Comment: @pme not really, and I personally dislike union types so I don't think I will play with them soon _(but the possibility remains)_. Still, that is why I made the answer a community wiki, so it is not bound only to my beliefs but that anyone can edit and add their own findings. - Anyways, since you mention you may have multiple `Options` fields, have you considered a builder pattern instead?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes that is what I have - Just wanted to 'play' with Union types that make the caller side quite nice without any implicits. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about Scala3. But you could simply do this:

```
case class Example[T](v: Option[T] = None)

object Example {
 def apply[T](t: T): Example[T] = Example(Some(t))
}
```

One could also go for implicit conversion, regarding the specific use case of the OP:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

case class Optable[Out](value: Option[Out])

object Optable {
  implicit def fromOpt[T](o: Option[T]): Optable[T] = Optable(o)
  implicit def fromValue[T](v: T): Optable[T] = Optable(Some(v))
}

case class SomeOpts(i: Option[Int], s: Option[String])

object SomeOpts {
  def apply(i: Optable[Int], s: Optable[String]): SomeOpts = SomeOpts(i.value, s.value)
}

println(SomeOpts(15, Some("foo")))
```

Comment: Yes that would work if there would only be one parameter - but I have up to 10 - and this would give you a lot of `apply` functions.

Comment: @pme Yes, but then you would avoid that problem with pattern matching. You would only have to deal with a simple Option. :)

Comment: Consider the most frequent usages of your API: you don't need to provide all possible variants of `apply`.

Comment: @pme How about the second solution?

Comment: That is the most elegant solution so far - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

We have a [specialized `Option`-like type for this purpose: `OptArg`](https://github.com/AVSystem/scala-commons/blob/master/commons-core/src/main/scala/com/avsystem/commons/misc/OptArg.scala) (in Scala 2 but should be easily portable to 3)

```scala
import com.avsystem.commons._

def gimmeLotsOfParams(
  intParam: OptArg[Int] = OptArg.Empty,
  strParam: OptArg[String] = OptArg.Empty
): Unit = ???

gimmeLotsOfParams(42)
gimmeLotsOfParams(strParam = "foo")
```

It relies on an implicit conversion so you have to be a little careful with it, i.e. don't use it as a drop-in replacement for `Option`.

The implementation of `OptArg` is simple enough that if you don't want external dependencies then you can probably just copy it into your project or some kind of "commons" library.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the following answer is incorrect. As of Scala 3.1, flow analysis is only able to check for nullability. More information is available on the [Scala book](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/explicit-nulls.html#flow-typing).

---

I think that the already given answer is probably better suited for the use case you proposed (exposing an API can can take a simple value and normalize it to an `Option`).

However, the question in the title is still interesting and I think it makes sense to address it.

What you are observing is a consequence of type parameters being *erased* at runtime, i.e. they only exist during compilation, while matching happens at runtime, once those have been *erased*.

However, the Scala compiler is able to perform flow analysis for union types. Intuitively I'd say there's probably a way to make it work in pattern matching (as you did), but you can make it work for sure using an `if` and `isInstanceOf` (not as clean, I agree):

```
case class Example[T](
    obj: Option[T] | T = None
) {
  lazy val maybeIn =
    if (obj.isInstanceOf[Option[_]]) {
      obj
    } else {
      Some(obj)
    }
}
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/S6RjjFr7QJqJBuq7QHASkQ/20).

[Here](https://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2019/12/20/21th-dotty-milestone-release.html) is the announcement from 2019 when flow analysis was added to the compiler.

Comment: Well if you put `Some(obj: T)` it doesn't compile. :D
So I think flow analysis doesnt kick in here.

Comment: I think this answers the title of the question the best - even the community thinks Union Types are not a good way to solve the Option Pattern.

Comment: I had a better look at this and indeed `maybeIn` is of type `Any`. Looking at the documentation it looks like flow analysis only applies to nullability checks. I wrote some TypeScript and I was expecting something more sophisticated. My bad. I'll edit the answer to make sure people are not drawn to false conclusions.